# Cython wrapper not fast enough, how to speed it up?

Tags: python, performance, cython

I have a C++ library and I want to wrap some of its functionality in python.

The function splits the given character array into 5 parts, not actual splitting but the structure we pass a pointer to, contains the information about the parts after the function returns. The 5 structures each contain 2 integers, one denoting the beginning of the part, and the other, the part's length.

The python wrapper should accept a python string and return a dictionary or tuple of the 5 parts(as python strings also).

My current approach of calling the function and then splitting the python string based on the sub-part information using python slicing syntax has not yielded any significant speed gains. I realize that there are many similar questions, but none of those cases have been helpful to me.

The Cython definition code is -

```
cdef extern from "parse.h" namespace util
    ctypedef struct part:
        int begin;
        int len;

    ctypedef struct Parsed:
        part part1;
        part part2;
        part part3;
        part part4;
        part part5;

    void ParseFunc(const char* url, int url_len, Parsed* parsed)
```

The Cython code is -

```
cimport parseDef

def parse(url, url_len):
    cdef parseDef.Parsed parsed
    parseDef.parseFunc(url, url_len, &parsed)

    part1 = url[parsed.part1.begin:parsed.part1.begin+parsed.part1.len]
    #similar code for other parts

    return (part1, part2, part3, part4, part5)
```

Typical string size for this wrapper will be 10-50 generally.

Comment: Really, don't need say "thanks" here.

Comment: Sorry for re-doing your edit, I though I had missed that part while copying the question from my text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a small benefit from doing the indexing on `const char*` instead of the string

```
cimport parseDef

def parse(url, url_len):
    cdef const char* url_as_char_ptr = url # automatic conversion
    cdef parseDef.Parsed parsed
    parseDef.parseFunc(url, url_len, &parsed)

    part1 = url_as_char_ptr[parsed.part1.begin:parsed.part1.begin+parsed.part1.len]
    #similar code for other parts

    return (part1, part2, part3, part4, part5)
```

I don't think you can beat this by much is that, mostly because the c-code generated is actually pretty efficient. The indexing line is translated to something like

```
__pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(__pyx_v_url_as_char_ptr + idx1, idx2 - idx1)
```

(noting that I've replaced `parsed.part1.begin` with `idx1` just for the sake of readability and because I'm testing this with slightly different code since I don't have `parseFunc`. You can check your exact code with `cython -a yourfile.pyx` and looking at the html output).

This is basically just calling the Python c-api string constructor function. That will necessarily make a copy of the string it is passed, but you can't avoid that (the Python string constructor always makes a copy). That doesn't leave a lot of overhead to remove.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that doing the slicing part in C++ would be helpful? If yes, how can I define the parts in C++ and how can I return them?

Comment: @qkrm14 I don't think you'll be able to do a lot better. I've added a bit of explanation about why I think it has managed to reduce it to the minimum possible code needed to build the Python string outputs.